# WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (4, 112, 112, 3) for input ..., but it was called on an input with incompatible shape ((None, 112)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I trained a model and saved it as a h5 file. When I reuse the model and try to make a prediction using an image, it throws an error saying that it is incompatible.

How can I eliminate the warning?

Here is the code:

```
CATEGORIES = ["Tuberculosis", "Normal"]

def prepare(filepath):
  IMG_SIZE = 112
  img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
  new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
  return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 1)

model = tf.keras.models.load_model("tuberculosis.h5")

prediction = model.predict([prepare("test.jpg")])
print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][0])])
```

Here is the error it throws:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (4, 112, 112, 3) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(4, 112, 112, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='conv2d_input'), name='conv2d_input', description="created by layer 'conv2d_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 112).


ValueError                                
Traceback (most 
recent call last)
<ipython-input-79-6d3f8245e17a> in <module>()
----> 1 prediction = model.predict([prepare("test.jpg")])
      2 print(CATEGORIES[int(prediction[0][0])])

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist- 
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in 
autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad- 
except
1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
1148             else:
1149                  raise

ValueError: in user code:

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1801, in predict_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1790, in step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1783, in run_step  **
    outputs = model.predict_step(data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1751, in predict_step
    return self(x, training=False)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/input_spec.py", line 228, in assert_input_compatibility
    raise ValueError(f'Input {input_index} of layer "{layer_name}" '

ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "sequential" (type Sequential).

Input 0 of layer "conv2d" is incompatible with the layer: expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 112)

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=('tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 112), dtype=uint8)',)
  • training=False
  • mask=None
```

Comment: We don't work with *images* of code, please see how to make a [mre].

Comment: @desertnaut is that better?

Comment: It certainly is, but still there is not enough info to answer

Comment: @desertnaut what should I add? Model summary?

Comment: I mean that we don't have any way of knowing what was the training data format after whatever preprocessing, and how it compares with the format of the data you are now trying to predict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error came from shape of input, You can try this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2

IMAGE_CHANNEL = 1 # or 3

def prepare(filepath):
    IMG_SIZE = 112
    img_array = cv2.imread(filepath, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, IMAGE_CHANNEL)

x = tf.keras.Input(shape=(112,112,IMAGE_CHANNEL))
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(16, activation='softmax')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(x, y)
model.summary()


prediction = model.predict([prepare("test.jpg")])
print(prediction)
```

Output:

```
Model: "model_11"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_17 (InputLayer)       [(None, 112, 112, 1)]     0         
                                                                 
 dense_13 (Dense)            (None, 112, 112, 16)      32        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 32
Trainable params: 32
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
[[[[2.40530210e-15 1.25257872e-18 2.81339079e-01 ... 1.10927344e-20
    1.28210900e-22 3.45369773e-24]
   [1.21484684e-15 5.40451430e-19 2.79041141e-01 ... 4.33733043e-21
    4.56826763e-23 1.14132918e-24]
   [3.09763760e-16 1.00567346e-19 2.74375856e-01 ... 6.62814917e-22
    5.79706900e-24 1.24585123e-25]
   ...
```

Answer (score 0):

the error is saying you are passing a wronly shapped image, input with 3 channels. This might work if your input image has 3 channels:

```
def prepare(filepath):
  IMG_SIZE = 112
  img_array = cv2.imread(filepath)
  img_array = cv2.cvtColor(img_array ,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
  return new_array.reshape(-1, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3)
```